# WebSocket DISCONNECT after handshake with Django-EEL

Tags: django, django-channels, eel

I am trying to use EEL + Django. i found this solution in this GitHub [link](https://github.com/seLain/Django-Eel).

I managed to make Django find the eel.js. but the issue it disconnect just after making WebSocket handshaking.

as below:-

```
    You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, content types, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
January 31, 2021 - 17:22:47
Django version 3.1.5, using settings 'demo.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.0 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
HTTP GET /example/operations 200 [0.03, 127.0.0.1:57173]
HTTP GET /eel/eel.js 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:57173]
Not Found: /favicon.ico
HTTP GET /favicon.ico 404 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:57173]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /eel [127.0.0.1:57177]
Exception inside application: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Projects\V1830Center\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Python Projects\V1830Center\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 160, in __call__
    send,
  File "D:\Python Projects\V1830Center\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\compatibility.py", line 33, in new_application
    instance = application(scope)
  File "D:\Python Projects\V1830Center\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 23, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
WebSocket DISCONNECT /eel [127.0.0.1:57177]
```

Project Tree:

[image]

Settings.py

```
    """
Django settings for demo project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2a1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-!d$idwr9=e0e82xi=78hjc0vhtfyh45r@)*(1@vt+dqzryips5'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'django_eel',
    'example',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'demo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'demo.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = "demo.routing.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'example/assets/'


STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'example/templates/example/assets/'),
)

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

routing.py:

```
   from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.conf.urls import url
from django_eel.consumers import EelConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    "websocket": URLRouter([
        url(r"^eel$", EelConsumer), # do not alter this line
    ]),
})
```

I wanted this solution to be able to use API + EEL methods together. so if anyone can help me with this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for this problem,

that i added .as_asgi() to the routing.py file.

```
   from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.conf.urls import url
from django_eel.consumers import EelConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    "websocket": URLRouter([
        url(r"^eel$", EelConsumer.as_asgi()), # do not alter this line
    ]),
})
```